# Incrementing a number where each digit has a different base

Tags: programming, modular-arithmetic

Let's say I have a list, for instance {10,5,3}, indicating the bases for each digit of my 3-digit number. Using this basis, if I wanted to increment {8,4,1} a couple of times, here's what I would get:

```
{8,3,1} -> {9,3,1} -> {0,4,1} -> ... -> {9,4,1} -> {0,0,2} -> and so on
```

Now I can go ahead and do this using loops like one would normally do. But I'm sure there's a more elegant way of implementing this using some of Mathematica's already existing functions. Can anybody think of a sleek way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What happens when you increment {9,4,2}? What base is the fourth digit in?

Comment: *P.S.* I like this question. It's like incrementing a time in ss:mm:hh-DD/MM/YYYY format.

Comment: To aid in searches, I'd like to note that a number with different bases for each digit is commonly known as a _mixed radix_ number.

Comment: @wxffles, thank you very much! I was just looking for that term (one of those you know it once you know things...)

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why not just use some combination of `IntegerDigits`, `FromDigits` and `MixedRadix` - all built-ins...

Answer (score 7):

You have several options, either directly implementing `incr`

```
incr[digs_, base_] := Module[{carry = 1, ndigs = digs, k = 1, nd},
  While[k <= Length[digs],
   {carry, nd} = 
    QuotientRemainder[Part[ndigs, k] + carry, Part[base, k]];
   Part[ndigs, k] = nd;
   If[carry == 0, Break[]]; k++;
   ];
  ndigs
  ]
```

Or implementing `FromMultpleBase` and `ToMultipleBase` functions to make your tuple to a natural number, and back:

```
FromMultipleBase[digs_, base_] := digs.FoldList[Times, 1, Most[base]]

ToMultipleBase[num_, base_] := 
 Part[Rest[
   FoldList[QuotientRemainder[Last[#1], #2] &, {0, num}, 
    Reverse[FoldList[Times, 1, Most[base]]]]], 
  Range[Length[base], 1, -1], 1]
```

Here is the usage:

```
In[152]:= NestList[inc[#, {10, 5, 3}] &, {8, 3, 1}, 12]

Out[152]= {{8, 3, 1}, {9, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 1}, {3, 
  4, 1}, {4, 4, 1}, {5, 4, 1}, {6, 4, 1}, {7, 4, 1}, {8, 4, 1}, {9, 4,
   1}, {0, 0, 2}}

In[153]:= FromMultipleBase[#, {10, 5, 3}] & /@ %

Out[153]= {88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100}

In[154]:= NestList[
 ToMultipleBase[
   FromMultipleBase[#, {10, 5, 3}] + 1, {10, 5, 3}] &, {8, 3, 1}, 12]

Out[154]= {{8, 3, 1}, {9, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 1}, {3, 
  4, 1}, {4, 4, 1}, {5, 4, 1}, {6, 4, 1}, {7, 4, 1}, {8, 4, 1}, {9, 4,
   1}, {0, 0, 2}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's see some beautiful answers pop up. For now, a not too sleek one to break the ice

```
fix[l_, base_] := 
 Module[{take = 0}, 
  Rest@FoldList[
    QuotientRemainder[#2[[1]] + take, #2[[2]]] /. {q_, 
        r_} :> (take = q; r) &, 0, Transpose@{l, base}]]

inc[{f_, rest___}, base_] := fix[{f + 1, rest}, base]
```

So

```
NestList[inc[#, {10, 5, 3}] &, {8, 3, 1}, 5]

(* {{8, 3, 1}, {9, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on Rojo's answer:

```
add[base_][l_, x_] := 
 FoldList[QuotientRemainder @@ ({1, 0} # + #2) &, x, {l, base}\[Transpose]][[2 ;;, 2]]

NestList[add[{10, 5, 3}][#, 1] &, {8, 3, 1}, 15]
```

> {{8, 3, 1}, {9, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1}, {4, 4, 1}, {5, 4, 1}, {6, 4, 1}}

Alternate formulation:

```
base /: base[l_, blst_] + x_Integer := 
 FoldList[QuotientRemainder @@ ({1, 0} # + #2) &, x, {l, blst}\[Transpose]][[2 ;;, 2]]

base[{8, 3, 1}, {10, 5, 3}] + Range[8]
```

> {{9, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1}, {4, 4, 1}, {5, 4, 1}, {6, 4, 1}}

Comment: Nice touches +1

Answer (score 3):

@cartonn's clock:

```
 Dynamic[Thread[Mod[{Clock[{8, 17, 1}, 5], Clock[{3, 7, 1}, 25],
       Clock[{1, 3, 1}, 75]}, {10, 5, 3}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: At first I thought synchronization might be a problem for three independent instances of `Clock` but looking at 'More Information' it seems this should be all right (*The base for all times used by `Clock` is the creation time of the cell in which Clock appears.*)

Comment: @Sjoerd, I thought I could concoct  something  with `DatePlus` but this, although it does not quite work yet (it needs finer tuning to avoid some skips), was hard to resist. Still `DatePlus` seems more promising.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't think `DatePlus` could be (ab)used for that. Can you give it units other than "Day" etc. to work with?

Comment: I think you can only use combinations of built-in date/time units, but day,hour,minute values can be non-integers.

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing the point here, but I think in this case functional programming may drag efficiency down...

```
incr[list_, {a_, b_, c_}, n_ : 1] :=
   With[ {check = {Mod[#[[1]], a] , Mod[#[[2]], b] + Quotient[ #[[1]],a], Mod[#[[3]], c] 
         + Quotient[#[[2]],b]} &},
         NestList[check[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]], #[[3]]}] &, list, n]]
```

`Quotient` added on J.M.'s suggestion.

Comment: The `Floor[p/q]` bits in your code can of course be done as `Quotient[p, q]`.

Comment: @J.M. I should have seen that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 10.2, `MixedRadix[]` has been built-in. Its convention (most significant digits first) is the reverse of the OP's, however.

Thus, borrowing Sasha's example:

```
d = {1, 3, 8}; mr = MixedRadix[{3, 5, 10}];
Table[IntegerDigits[FromDigits[d, mr] + k, mr], {k, 0, 12}]
   {{1, 3, 8}, {1, 3, 9}, {1, 4, 0}, {1, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 4, 4},
    {1, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {1, 4, 8}, {1, 4, 9}, {2, 0, 0}}
```

Apply `Reverse[]` if needed.

Comment: +1, I was puzzled (per my comment) why all the machinations when it's built-in...